# How to set values to jtable?

Tags: java, jtable

I have two tables in my database(using mysql workbench), but I can't set the data in that tables at the same time to **jtable**. How can I fix this issue ?
**(Get the values from two tables or related fields and set those into jtable)**

Comment: Can you get the values from one table and populate the JTable? do you know how to create the ResultSet? Do you know how to take the data from the ResultSet to the TableModel of the JTable? What is your exact problem?

Comment: yes I can populate, but how can I populate the JTable using two tables(DB)? jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)); I mean two resultsets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean two resultsets?

Why do you have two ReultSets? You have two options:

1. Change your SQL query to get the data into a single ResultSet
2. Don't use DBUtils to create the TableModel

In this case you need to load the data from the ResultSet manually one row at a time.

For the first ResultSet you need to create the columns for the table and then add rows of data. The basic logic would be:

```
    Vector<Object> columnNames = new Vector<Object>();
    Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();

    //  Read data from a table

    String sql = "Select * from ???";
    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql );
    ResultSetMetaData md = rs.getMetaData();
    int columns = md.getColumnCount();

    //  Get column names

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        columnNames.addElement( md.getColumnName(i) );
    }

    //  Get row data

    while (rs.next())
    {
        Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>(columns);

        for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
        {
            row.addElement( rs.getObject(i) );
        }

        data.addElement( row );
    }

    rs.close();
    stmt.close();
    connection.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println( e );
}
```

For the second ResultSet you just add the data to the Vector.

Then you create the DefaultTableModel using the two Vectors and you create the JTable using the TableModel.

Comment: Thank You very much for your support. This is really helpful for me :) :)